# contains() method is not working

Tags: grails

I receive JSON data as below,

```
def data = JSON.parse(params.company) //it's [name:foo, users:[1,2,3]]
```

And I want to check if it contained. I did like this,

```
if(data.users.contains(2)){
  println 'true'
}
else {
 println 'false'
}
```

It's always print 'false'

But when I try by new data like

```
def test = [1,2,3]
if(test.contains(2)){
  println 'true'
}
else {
 println 'false'
}
```

It's 'true'.

Comment: could you please show us what `data.users` really is?  e.g. `println data.users.inspect()`

Comment: @cfrick , Now it is ['1','2','3']. They have single quote.

Comment: @cfrick I have to parse it to String in the contains method.
like data.users.contains(2.toString()). It's worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although you said in a comment that you solved it, I think you did it the wrong way.

You should try

```
def test = [1,2,3]
if(test.contains('2')){
  println 'true'
}
else {
 println 'false'
}
```

You have to understand that 2 == '2' is false. Types matters.